# How to change exception message?

Tags: php

Inside my code base I have a something like this:

```
function saveApples($apples) {
  try {
    write2DB($apples); // this function can throw Exception
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    throw $e;
  }
}
```

which works just fine.
What if I'd like to add some "context" info to exception message?
For example prepending the text: *"Sorry, can't store apples: "* to it?

**UPDATE**: To answer to DDeme comment, I suppose write2DB() function throws a meaningful exception, which I want to pass up...

Comment: if(!write2DB($apples)) {throw new Exception("Sorry, can't store apples"); }
you can add this in try block;

Comment: so you want custom exception to maintain Exception $e and also have another from write2db function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add some text to the constructor.

e.g.

```
function saveApples($apples) {
  try {
    write2DB($apples);
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    throw new Exception('Sorry, can\'t store apples', 0, $e);
  }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: See my update... This way you'd loose the important error message thrown by write2DB()... :-(

Comment: The portion of the answer that says ",0 ,$e" chains the exceptions together so that the new exception with your useful message now has a reference to the original exception.  I believe this handles your case of wanting to have visibility into the first exception but also having a custom message.

Comment: With the edit from Wpigott it's exact what you want. We take the exception that write2DB raises and add a message. What more do you need ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed `0, $e`... Thanks!

Comment: this is not worked for me, copy the exact catch and still the custom message not displayed